# Azure Mobile Services SSO across W8.1 and WP8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8, single-sign-on, windows-8.1, azure-mobile-services

**What I want**

I want to allow in app SSO between the Live Connect SDK and a single Mobile Services instance that I'll use as the backend for 2 applications, WP8 & W8.1. I want to do this without affecting existing users of the WP8 app that is already in the Windows Phone Store. Both apps will use the Live SDK for OneDrive access.

**Existing Situation**

I have a Windows Phone 8 application that uses Azure Mobile Services and the Live Connect SDK and I have set up SSO by

- Registering the app in the Live Connect Developer Center
- Setting the redirect URL in the Developer Center to the Mobile Services URL (used in the Live Connect authentication token)
- Copying the Client ID into my app and passing it to the Live Connect SDK methods when I log in
- Retrieving the Live Connect authentication token after login and passing it to the Mobile services login

**Issues**

This is fine but now I want to start building a companion Windows 8.1 app that uses the same Mobile Services instance and SSO but I'm running into a difficulty as below:

- The Live Connect Developer Center app associated with the Windows 8.1 app needs to have the Package SID and the only way I can find to do this is to use the 'associate my app with the Windows Store' tool within Visual Studio. This creates a new app in the Live Connect Developer Center with the Windows 8.1 Package SID. I can't find any way to add this Package SID to my existing Live Connect app (i.e. the one used for the WP8 app).
- I believe I need to use a single, shared Live Connect Developer Center app, and associated Client ID, for both my WP8 and W8.1 apps as the authentication token from Live Connect ([documentation here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826544.aspx#token_data)) seems to include the 'user identifier - uid' that is 'An identifier for the user, **which is unique to the app**'. To me this also implies that if I change the client ID (i.e. effectively a new app from Live Connect's point of view) then it will appear to mobile services as if a new user is signing in and all their old data will no longer be accessible to them.

I have researched other people doing SSO across both platforms and they seem to be using a single app in the Live Connect Developer Center but in all cases that I have seen so far they use the Windows 8.1 app, because this has the Package SID, and set it to 'Mobile or desktop client app'. I have started from the other direction with the phone app first and I can't find any information about this. I'm also trying to avoid testing this all out in a live app in case it does cause issues.

I have posted in both the [Mobile Services](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/e374bcc2-3ece-4d21-82fe-cff02a64e6be/live-connect-sso-across-w81-and-wp8?forum=azuremobile#e374bcc2-3ece-4d21-82fe-cff02a64e6be) and Live Connect forums about these issues but without a reply. (I can only provide 2 links, check my profile in the Mobile Services forum for my other post).

**My Question**

How can I add Azure Mobile Services SSO to my new Window 8.1 app without breaking my existing WP8 app?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has been answered by Matthew Henderson in the [Azure Mobile Services forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/e374bcc2-3ece-4d21-82fe-cff02a64e6be/live-connect-sso-across-w81-and-wp8?forum=azuremobile)

The simplified version is you need to use one Live Connect app in the Developer Center (i.e. the same Client ID used by both the W8.1 & WP8 apps)

To do this you either need to either:

a) Start with the Windows 8.1 app which will register the SID with the Live Connect app (this is the documented and easiest path) and then re-use this Client ID in the Windows Phone 8 app

OR

b) If you already have a Windows Phone 8 app as I did then you can change the automatically created SID association in the Live Connect Developer Center to allow the Windows 8.1 app to use the existing Windows Phone 8 Client ID. This is a less well documented feature.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this question may have already been covered here:

[Live Connect Authentication Token for use on Azure Mobile Services (REST)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994696/live-connect-authentication-token-for-use-on-azure-mobile-services-rest)

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I should have specified that I'm using the Live SDK because I also use OneDrive so I want to sign in once with Live Connect and then pass that token to Mobile Services. I think what you're talking about is if I was just using Mobile Services then I can sign in directly with that?

Comment: I edited my answer to link to another answer on SO that looks like it will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks again for the effort but that link does not answer my problem. I can get SSO to work with Live Connect and Mobile Services on EITHER WP8 or W8.1 but not with both WHEN I've started with a WP8 app first. I'll edit my original post to make it clearer